# Django: Bootstrap input group not rendering desired HTML/CSS with form

Tags: html, django, forms, django-forms, django-templates

I'm relatively new to Django and having an issue with rendering a form as an input group in Bootstrap. The form is to add a message to a model for a chat.

Here is what I am aiming for as an input group: [Expected input group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kezNl.png)

This can be achieved with the below HTML:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-append">
        <span class="input-group-text attach_btn"><i class="fas fa-paperclip"></i></span>
    </div>
    <textarea name="" class="form-control type_msg" placeholder="Type your message..."></textarea>
    <div class="input-group-append">
        <span class="input-group-text send_btn"><i class="fas fa-location-arrow"></i></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now using Django to include the form within the input group I am using the below:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text attach_btn"><i class="fas fa-paperclip"></i></span>
    </div>
    <form method="post" action=".">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.content }}
        <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="send_btn" type="submit"><i class="fas fa-location-arrow"></i></button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

This is using the below forms.py:

```
class JobMessageForm(ModelForm):
content = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={
    'class': 'form-control type_msg',
    'placeholder': 'Type your message...'}), label=False)

class Meta:
    model = JobMessage
    fields = ('content',)
```

This is giving me the below: [Current input group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zupd.png)

Any help in achieving the expected output would be greatly appreciated! Let me know if any further info would help.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the answer was to simply make the form itself an input group:

`<form class="input-group" method="post" action=".">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text attach_btn"><i class="fas fa-paperclip"></i></span>
    </div>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.content }}
    <div class="input-group-append">
        <button class="send_btn" type="submit"><i class="fas fa-location-arrow"></i></button>
    </div>
</form>`